# Posting data back to a controller from a Partial View rendered by Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am returning a Partial View from an Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#itemSubmitter").click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetShippingAddress", "Order")',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $("#shoppingAddressWrapper").html(data);

        }
    });
});
});
```

This returns the View as expected. However, the Partial has several Textboxes with data already populated. The #shoppingAddressWrapper is within a Form Tag.

When I submit the Form, the values in the Textboxes on the partial are not part of the Request.Params collection.

Is this normal? Can you not return input boxes as part of Partial View rendered via Ajax call and then post that data to the server and retrieve the values?

C

Comment: did you solve this problem, I am having the same issue, I have started a bounty.

Comment: I think the model binder is messing with the data.

Comment: Have you tried this in multiple browsers? I think I remember coming across this before...

Answer (score 1):

I have found what the problem is.
You need to clear the model state for the text boxes.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    ModelState.Clear();
```

You can clear just the values you need, or all the values. The ajax mechanism will otherwise insert the old values back.

Comment: Jim - I'd moved past my issue. Let me try to recreate this and try your solution because I know this scenario will come back! Thnx.