# MVC3 Partial View and Model not posting back changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Model than contains a collection of items that can be modified.

I render the collection using a Partial View, which in turn uses EditorForModel to output the HTML for each element in the collection.

```
@model Footy.Models.EventModel

    <h2>@Model.Team1Name vs @Model.Team2Name</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Event"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EventID)
        <h1>
            Team 1 Squad</h1>
        @Html.Partial("EventPlayers", Model.Team1Players);
        <h1>
            Team 2 Squad</h1>
   Html.RenderPartial("EventPlayers", Model.Team2Players);

        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Changes" />
    }
```

Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<Footy.Models.PlayerModel>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

PlayerModel View

```
@model Footy.Models.PlayerModel

@Model.PlayerName @Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ParticipationStatusID, new SelectList(Model.ParticipationTypes, "Key", "Value"))
```

It all renders correctly, but when the user clicks the input, the controller method is not passed the child collection in the model, e.g. Model.Team1Players is null

What am I missing?

EDIT: Generated HTML is

```
    <form action="/Footy/Event/Index/1" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EventID must be a number." data-val-required="The EventID field is required." id="EventID" name="EventID" type="hidden" value="1" />            
<h1>Team 1 Squad</h1>
      si <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ParticipationStatusID must be a number." data-val-required="The ParticipationStatusID field is required." name="[0].ParticipationStatusID"><option value="1">Team</option>
    <option value="2">Sub</option>
    <option value="3">Squad</option>
    </select>
    <h1>Team 2 Squad</h1>
 <input type="submit" value="Confirm Changes" />
 </form>
```

Thanks

I think it is related to this question, which doesn't yet have an answer: [Posting data back to a controller from a Partial View rendered by Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457967/posting-data-back-to-a-controller-from-a-partial-view-rendered-by-ajax)

Comment: hard to tell - can you go view this page in your browser and submit the generated HTML (show source or something similiar in your browser)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you inspect the rendered source, can you check that the names and id's of the rendered child model inputs correspond to the model hierarchy?

I believe that you will need `EditorFor` in order for the child models to be properly "namespaced".

So in the EventModel view, use something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Team1Players, "EventPlayers")
```

I am not sure however. I've had similar problems with the MVC framework.

Comment: Yes that was it. In addition I had to add a new Hidden field in the Partial View for the User ID, so I knew which Player I had to update with the new status.  Great stuff - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the collection binding.

Try reading [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx). It should give you some insight on collection binding