# MVC 4 Razor, Posting form with partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC 4 and razor.  I have a view which contains multiple partial views.  Due to the functionality of the partial views I am planning to reuse these in other views also.

My model is a collection of complex objects e.g:

```
    public class EmployeeInfo
    {
        public EmployeeContactInfo contactInfo { get; set; }
        public List<TelephoneInfo> phoneDetails { get; set; }
        public AddressDetails addressDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

The model of my main view is `EmployeeInfo` and other partial views have models as `TelephoneInfo`, `EmployeeContactInfo` and `AddressDetails` respectively.

I tried using `RenderPartial`, `RenderAction` and `Partial` to load my partial views e.g:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.Partial("ContactInfo",Model.contactInfo)
    }
```

When the main form is submitted the main model doesnt have the updated values of the partial views.

I searched for this and found below 2 proposed solutions:

1. Use `EditorFor` - It works and the model gets updated but I have collection of not only textbox but other controls which have some internal operations (like searching addresses) too and I also need to reuse the same partial view in other places (like a user control in classic ASP.NET)
2. Use `RenderAction` instead of `RenderPartial` - It didn't work for me.

Please let me know if I am going wrong or understood anything incorrectly.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687592/mvc3-partial-view-and-model-not-posting-back-changes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another choice is to create an [editor template](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx). For example, in your main view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @(Html.EditorFor(m => m.ContactInfo))
}
```

Now, in your Views/Shared folder (or the Views/ControllerName folder eg Views/Home), create a new folder named "EditorTemplates". In that new folder create a cshtml view file named `EmployeeContactInfo.cshtml` (tip, the name of the cshtml should be the data type name e.g. `string`, `bool` or in this case your customer contact info type). In that view file, put something like:

```
@model EmployeeContactInfo

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

When you post back to the controller, the values will be included as part of the returned model for you.

Comment: @indranilpal - Editor Templates are like Partial Views, except they are designed to be used in the manner you want to use them (as reusable components).  It allows you to render components based on their type, with the proper naming conventions to support complex nested objects.  It also supports collections of objects, and will render a collection as well.

Comment: @MystereMan - Exactly, I wanted something which I can reuse, I think editor templates will save my day. Thanks JasonEvans and thank you MysteryMan :)

Comment: Please note the semicolon at the end of the line. It is not necessary, in fact it prints the character to the HTML. Thanks!

Comment: @Diego Cheers. Have removed the `;` char.

Comment: Wow!  I just used this with .NET Core and the new Tag Helpers.  I thought it wouldn't work but it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pinski Glad this info help you out :)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that your main form is expecting elements with the name contactInfo.property, probably in you partial the names you generate are property without the right identifiers, this issue create problems with the default model binder of MVC.
You can create a custom model binder, but with hard work, or you have two ways to solve your issue with less work.

**1. Force the name of the generated element**

For example, if your `EmployeeContactInfo` class contains a string `Address` property you have to use this helper:

```
@Html.TextBox("contactInfo.Address", model.Address)
```

that results in:

```
<input type="text" name="contactInfo.Address" id="contactInfo_Address" />
```

instead of:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Address)
```

that results in:

```
<input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" />
```

**2. Pass the entire model:**

If you pass the entire model the generated name would be correct, so you can use the helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.contactInfo.Address)
```

that results in:

```
<input type="text" name="contactInfo.Address" id="contactInfo_Address" />
```

Comment: Pass the entire model works, I agree, but for the view to be resued at other places I dont want other views to create a new model and map from their actual models everytime. I also thought about the "name" in control, but it doesnt work if you put it in htmlAttributes list when the controls are rendered, the name changes back to the property name

Answer (score -2):

Partial View page acts like User Control

1. Here _login.cshtml is partial view
2. If you use partial view then underscore followed by name:

   `<div style = "margin:3%;">`
   `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_login.cshtml",Model.login)`
   `</div>`
3. Model.login is a object. So in this object you can assign value whatever page.
4. Partial will show based on object value.

Comment: I believe you are using sample code from a project and the code as-is does not help the user for this specific question