# How to add elements dynamically in a view without model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make an examination portal. I want to add a textbox for a question and then add a button which dynamically adds textbox for options for the given question(number of options is not predefined. A question can have 2,3,4,5... options as per users need). My questions are being stored in a separate model and my answers would be stored in a separate model. Is it possible?? How??

I have looked up at different places but everywhere I only found ways to add elements dynamically with model binding. But since I am using two different models in a single view, I believe model binding would not be possible!! 
Guide me through this!!

Comment: Hi Rohit, 
tried with Partial views and binding the model data to them? As in Html.RenderPartial("QuestionPartial", Model.Question) and Html.RenderPartial("ResposnePartial", Model.Respons). This should work if you only have one question/response on one page.

Comment: Do you have any example or links to those.. bcoz I don't know how to implement this?? I have studied about partial views but don't have much knowledge about it ..

Comment: You could also try editor templates, which perhaps even does suite better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420751/mvc-4-razor-posting-form-with-partial-views - I would go for this at first. For your sample, just subclass your Model in two nested classes and pass these to the RenderPartialView - the form itself does only go into the ResponsePartial where the Response Model is passed to. In your post action, simply use the ResponsePartialModel for verification.

Comment: My aim is to retrieve data from the view into the database . I know how to send the data , but m not able to figure out how I can save data from the view into two different models, i.e. how I can post two models from a single view.

Comment: Simpy include 2 Models in the 1 Model you pass. As in public class PageModel { public QuestionModel Question {get;set;} public ResponseModel Response {get;set;}} - then pass the PageModel to the View and access the other models with @Model.Question