# Missing order details from edited order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why I get the order inside the HttpPost `Edit()` method with empty OrderDetails collection? Is it expected in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks.

Orders controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   Order order = GetOrderById(id);

   return View(order);
}        

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Order order)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {                                 
       context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
       context.SaveChanges();
       // HERE order.OrderDetails is empty even if it was filled with a number of items
   }

   return View(order);
}

private Order GetOrderById(int id)
{
    return context.Orders.Single(x => x.orderID == id);
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public int orderID { get; set; }
    public int customerID { get; set; }
    public string promoCodeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual PromoCode PromoCode { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**

View:

```
@using Corporate.Models
@model Corporate.Models.Order

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{       
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
       </div>
    </div>    

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.taxes)
}
```

Partial `_CreateOrEdit` full of stuff like this, nothing else:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.orderID, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.orderID, new { @class = "form-control datepicker"})
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.orderID)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your http request look like?

Comment: @gmoney: `http://localhost:55058/Orders/Edit/102969`

Comment: Please show your view code also, as the issue could be there.

Comment: @gmoney: Does this mean that I should see `Order.OrderDetails` properly populated?

Comment: What's in `_CreateOrEdit`?  I see nothing in the View that would populate `OrderDetails`

Comment: If you do not generate any form controls for `OrderDetails`, then it will not be submitted back to he server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking one more stab at this, as I expect the real "issue" here is a misunderstanding on how MVC handles data as you move through an application - leaving my previous answer intact as there is some useful information there, though I'll gladly drop it if asked.

For starters, stephen.vakil's comment on my original answer has some useful information (emphasis mine):

> The only thing that will be in your posted object are things that the model binder can map from your html fields. **Once your view is rendered, whatever objects you had are no longer in memory.** When you submit the form, the mvc API will take anything it finds in Request.Form and try to match it against fields in your model. Everything else is left blank (or, in this case, as a new empty HashSet). **If you want your OrderDetails to be there on post, either load the object again, or persist the data in some way** (via Hidden or otherwise).

Basically, when you load a View, you're performing a `GET` request. In your case, your `GET` method takes in an order ID:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   Order order = GetOrderById(id);

   return View(order);
} //get the order by ID, and pass it down to the view
```

With this `GET` request, your `View` page will hold the data you expect (assuming an order was found for the ID given) and, assuming your view is set up for it, you should be able to see the `OrderDetails` - so all is well here.

**Note that at this point, your `GET` request has performed its duties and tossed aside the `Order` object it was holding - as far as the controller is concerned, there's no use for this anymore.**

For the next bit, here's a simplified view to work with:

```
@using Corporate.Models
@model Corporate.Models.Order

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.orderID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.customerID)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

When you click `Submit` on this view, your `POST` method gets called:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Order order)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {                                 
       context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
       context.SaveChanges();
       // HERE order.OrderDetails is empty even if it was filled with a number of items
   }

   return View(order);
}
```

When we get here, **a new `Order` object is created from the data in your form!** In the case of the simplified view, this means your new `Order` object only has the `orderID` and `customerID` properties (and an empty `HashSet`, generated from the `Order` constructor) - **anything else that got loaded into the view is dropped because it was not part of the submitted data.**

---

### Posting all of your data back to the controller

If you want this data to persist into the `POST` request, **you need to tell your form to store it.**

There are a number of ways to do this, likely the easiest being `@Html.HiddenFor()`. `HiddenFor` essentially just holds a reference to a particular property so it isn't lost, *even if you don't want that data visible on the form.* You can still display the data however you choose, but unless your form is explicitly told to, it won't pass the information back on post.

Taking the same view, let's add some additional properties:

```
@using Corporate.Models
@model Corporate.Models.Order

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Orders", FormMethod.Post))
{       
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.orderID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.customerID)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    //these values will all be POSTed back exactly as they were passed down in the GET request  
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.promoCodeID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Customer.Prop1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Customer.Prop2) //etc - these objects need all of their properties bound to the form
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderDetails.Prop1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PromoCode.Prop1)
}
```

Notice that I've added `HiddenFor`s to the remaining properties in your model. Now, the form has explicitly been told about the properties, and will pass them into your `POST` request. So when the `POST` request creates a new `Order` object, it will have these properties to work with.

Note that for complex objects (`Customer` for example, thanks @stephen muecke) you'll need to bind the individual properties to post back to the form - see an example [here](http://www.henry-chong.com/mvc-model-binding-complex-objects-and-collections).

So with that, your controller will receive all the data it needs to fully recreate the object, even if you don't want the user editing some or all of it.

Boiling all of this down into one sentence, **your form will only pass back the data it's explicitly told to pass back - either by using `Hidden` or some other method.**

---

As a final note here, please understand that your `@Html.Partial()` is not *technically* a part of your form - it's more complicated than that, but that's the important bit to take away.

If you want the information in your `Partial` to be posted, you should consider making it an `EditorTemplate` (described in my original answer, and elsewhere on this site). An `EditorTemplate` is essentially a fancy form field, and any information stored there will be passed back on `POST`.

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Customer)`,  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderDetails)` and `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PromoCode)` will not work (those properties are complex objects/collections)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Woops, thanks! Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt, but my guess is that your `@Html.Partial` isn't posting updated data back to your form - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687592/mvc3-partial-view-and-model-not-posting-back-changes) for additional info. Basically, MVC generates all this info dynamically and the `Partial` likely isn't binding back to your model.

For this data to post, you probably want to turn this partial into an `EditorTemplate` and use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDetails, "nameOfEditorTemplate")`. Once that's updated, you should see the `OrderDetails` properly populated.

EDIT:

`EditorTemplates` live in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. All you really need to do is move your current `PartialView` there and update your form to use `EditorFor` instead of `Partial`.

EDIT 2:

Seeing your `_CreateOrEdit` view, turning that into an `Editor` should give your `Order` model an `ID` on the `POST` action. So in your `POST` method, you probably want to call `GetOrder ByID()` with that ID and get the `OrderDetails` from there.

Whichever route you choose to go, the reason you're not getting this info on `POST` is your model has nothing to bind to - It's not getting passed from View to Controller because it's not a part of your form. If you either make this `Partial` an `Editor` or move the `OrderID` to your form, you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: I don't need to edit order details, just to see them once the edit operation is completed.

Comment: @Alberto The underlying reason for this not being loaded on `POST` is that you're not storing it in your form anywhere. You either need a `HiddenFor` or, assuming the order gets loaded in `_CreateOrEdit`, turn him into an editor. Even if nothing ultimately gets changed, this will bind the info on `POST` so you have it available in your controller.

Comment: @Alberto another option is to store the info in `ViewData`, `TempData` or `ViewBag` (http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/ for a decent writeup on the diferences). One way or another, you need to hold this data somewhere between your `GET` and `POST`.

Comment: Are you sure? `OrderDetails` are not like `orderID`, they represent a link to a different table on the `orderID` key.

Comment: @Alberto how are you expecting to load OrderDetails? Are they loaded with `GetOrderByID()` ?

Comment: The only thing that will be in your posted object are things that the model binder can map from your html fields.  Once your view is rendered, whatever objects you had are no longer in memory.  When you submit the form, the mvc API will take anything it finds in `Request.Form` and try to match it against fields in your model.  Everything else is left blank (or, in this case, as a new empty `HashSet`).  If you want your `OrderDetails` to be there on post, either load the object again, or persist the data in some way (via Hidden or otherwise).